# How can I clear out a picklist and a textbox?

Tags: visualforce

I have two pick-lists, one textbox and one button called Clear, now I want to clear textbox and reset pick-list on click of clear button.

this.form.reset(); is not worked because i have used action-function.

I need any custom function. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form.reset() not working you can write another method in controller

public static void resetFields(){

picklistField = 'Deafult value you want to pass';

textField = '';

}

call this method on button click.

Comment: but i have one action function in page can i add one more action function for that ?

Comment: If you post your code I could have suggested more better